# Region of controllability for optimal control

Tags: optimization, systems-of-equations, optimal-control

I have an optimal control question which yields:

$x=A e^{4t}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\end{pmatrix}+B e^{2t}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}1\\3\end{pmatrix}u^*$

For $u^* = \pm1$

So we can see from the eigenvalues we have these two repulsive nodes centred at $(1,3)$ and $(-1,-3)$

Is the region of controllability just the rectangle created from the lines of the eigenvectors?

Comment: What eigenvalues are you referring to? What do you mean by $u* = \pm 1$? Do you mean $u^*(t) \in \{-1,1\}$ ?

Comment: @copper.hat It means that there are two nodes, one with $u=1$ one with $u=-1$, and the eigenvalues are $\lambda = 2,4$ as seen as exponents of $e$, sorry if this was opaque. Corresponding eigenvectors are attached to their eigenvalue in $e$ above

Comment: @copper.hat Oh now I feel silly, you were probably referring to my typo, I meant the lines of the eigen vectors, sorry if I was rude likely pointing out the obvious fact about :S